# How to understand "-input[range(target.shape[0]), target]"?

Tags: python, pytorch

In [the official example of PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nn_tutorial.html), it gives a loss function as follows.

```
def nll(input, target):
    return -input[range(target.shape[0]), target].mean()

loss_func = nll
```

How to understand the grammar of "**input[range(target.shape[0]), target]**" in the above function?
"input" has a torch.Size([64, 10]) and "target" has a torch.Size([64]). Why use "**range**" function here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range function is used as a shortcut to create a vector/list/generator starting from 0 up to 64. So it is shorthand for essentially [0,1,2,...64]

To make this explicit you could do the following:

```
def nll(input, target):
    minputlist = list(range(target.shape[0]))
    print(minputlist )
    return -input[minputlist, target].mean()
```

Comment: Why I get error when directly run `a = np.random.randn(3,2)
b = np.random.randn(3)
a[range(b.shape[0]),b] ` ?